# Removing files that have special characters in their name

Tags: linux, rm

How do I remove files, with specific names.. For example, my file name is

```
This File Example (England).txt
This File Example (US).txt
```

I want to remove all the files with (England) in the name.

So I tried,

```
rm -f "*(Eng*"
```

But it doesn't work. Is there something needed for special chars?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
rm -f ./*'(England)'*
```

Comment: Or just `rm -f *(England)*`

Comment: @Droow That doesn't work.

Comment: @iBug Yes it does https://imgur.com/a/IBeFy, but maybe my ZSH is automatically escaping it for me ;)

Comment: @Droow I use Bash and it fails. Zsh isn't the default shell on most systems :)

Answer (score 0):

Escape the special ones:

```
rm -f *\(Eng*
       ^
```

Or use single quotes for literal parts:

```
rm -f *'(Eng'*
       ^    ^
```

Comment: rm -f *'(Eng'*     worked.. Thanks!

Comment: @Borg357 You can always accept answer that you deem helpful by clicking the grey tick beside it.

Comment: This glitches on filenames that start with `-`, which is why I recommend using `./` at the start of the glob pattern.